# solving Improper integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I have a problem when I tried to solve the following improper integral
I think it could be solved using Residue theorem, but I don't how to crack it , and I don't know if there is a closed form for this problem
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin(sin(t-\theta))e^{cos(t-\theta)}}{t^{1/2}} dt$$ $\ where\ \theta >0$

I faced this problem while I'm trying to find the fractional derivative of a function using one of the definitions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My two cents is that this in principle could be attacked using Cauchy's Theorem but the form looks a bit hard to work with, i.e., the estimates of the integral over a large arc look hard to prove they vanish.  And even if you get that far, you end up having to deal with an integral like $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \, e^{a e^{-t^2}}$$ with $a$ complex and that looks pretty tough.

Comment: $$ \int_0^{\infty} x^{s-2} \sin(\sin(x)) \: e^{\cos(x)} dx = \frac{\Gamma(s)\cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})} {(1-s)} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^{1-s}}{k!} $$ May be useful. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a closed form is possible, even with contour integration, but I was able to get a fairly clean result;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(\sin(t-\theta))\cdot e^{\cos(t-\theta)}\over t^{1\over 2}}dt=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{i(\sin(t-\theta))}\cdot e^{\cos(t-\theta)}\over t^{1\over 2}}dt\right\}$$

$$=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{e^{i(t-\theta)}}\over t^{1\over 2}}dt\right\}=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}{{e^{i(nt-n\theta)}}\over t^{1\over 2}}dt\right\}$$

$$=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{e^{-in\theta}\over n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-{1\over 2}}\cdot{{e^{i(nt)}}}dt\right\}$$

$$=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{-{1\over2}}}dt+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-in\theta}\over n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-{1\over 2}}\cdot{{e^{i(nt)}}}dt\right\}$$

The integral that we have split off from our sum diverges. However, because we are only concerned with the imaginary part, it never becomes an issue. Focusing on the term containing the infinite sum and applying the substitution $u=-int$ gives us...

$$\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-in\theta}\over n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-{1\over 2}}\cdot{{e^{i(nt)}}}dt\right\}=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-in\theta}\over n\cdot n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg({-u\over in}\bigg)^{-{1\over 2}}\cdot{{e^{-u}}}du\right\}$$

$$=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\sqrt{i}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-in\theta}\over \sqrt{n}\cdot n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}{u}^{-{1\over 2}}\cdot{{e^{-u}}}du\right\}=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\sqrt{i\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-in\theta}\over \sqrt{n}\cdot n!}\right\}$$

$$=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\sqrt{\pi}\left({1\over \sqrt{2}}+{i\over \sqrt{2}}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(\cos(n\theta)-i\sin(n\theta))\over \sqrt{n}\cdot n!}\right\}$$

Finally, some quick multiplication yields our answer;

$$=\sqrt{\pi\over2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(\cos(n\theta)-\sin(n\theta))\over \sqrt{n}\cdot n!}$$

Comment: Good work!!, but I have reached the last summation directly from your second line $$=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{e^{i(t-\theta)}}\over t^{1\over 2}}dt\right\}=\mathfrak{Im}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}{{e^{i(nt-n\theta)}}\over t^{1\over 2}}dt\right\}$$ and using the fact $$∫_0^∞t^s   sin⁡(at+b)dt=a^{-s-1}  Γ(1+s)  cos⁡(b+πs/2)$$
and then I stuck with the last sum which you have reached,

 is there anyway to crack this hard nut?

Comment: @MohammadHussein I don't know of any way the sum can be easily simplified. I'm sure there is someone on the site that might be able to put some clever upper and lower bound on it....